# Supremum - Does $x \leq A$ for all x in X imply sup X $\leq A$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose we have a set $X$. We know $ \sup X $ is a real number. My question is
if we have that $x \leq A $ for all $x \in X$ and $A$ is a real number. Does it follow that $ \sup X \leq A $ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. It follows from the definition of supremum, since $A$ is an upper bound for $X$, and the supremum of $X$ is the least upper bound.